# Script to move mouse every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, vbscript, scripting, dom-events

I am trying to write a simple script that will move my mouse every 5 minutes if it has been idle. I am familiar with Java and **C**  but I have never written a script before.

I've tried VBS and JavaScript but I can't seem to find a way to determine when the mouse has moved. Does anyone have some advice?

Comment: Are you talking about "Java" or JavaScript", and do you know the difference between the two?

Comment: Why do you want to move your mouse like that? If you want to stop screensavers, sleep then there are ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you could take a look at the Robot class [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) that will allow you to move the mouse directly from your program.

You can also use a mouse-motion listener to check if the mouse has been moved, check [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html), or MouseInfo, as indicated in the first comment below.

Comment: [MouseInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html) may be more useful to get information about the mouse's location.

Comment: I was originally trying that but then I realized that I needed to record mouse movements for the whole screen. The script needs to be running in the background and I wasn't sure if a java program could record mouse events without a panel having focus...

Comment: a java program can run in background

Answer (score 0):

You can use onmousemove

I prefer query but you can do it with onmousemove js event 
http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

You should have a global variable and set the time when last moved. Also put a timeout (setTimeout('update()', 1);) for five minutes and check when the mouse has last moved.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). It's a script language for Windows automation.